# Image Blured in Iframe - Fix with CSS or JS?

Tags: javascript, css, iframe

on my site I have an iFrame which contains products that I sell.

When viewed on a desktop PC it's fine, but when viewed on a mobile / tablet device the image doesn't resize properly. The image in the iframe is blurred because it has been stretched to fit the screen. If you rotate the device or resize the screen by even a pixel it fixes it.

An example product is here: 
[Click and view as a mobile device](https://www.thefootballclubshop.com/water-bottles/brighton-hove-albion-fc-aluminium-water-bottle)

I have a css attached to the iframe so I can control what happens inside, but I can't figure this one out.

I've applied this to the canvas but it just stretches the image, it doesn't resize it:

```
height:100% !important;
width:100% !important;
```

It seems to be getting controlled by some js from the origin server, is there something simple that I'm missing here?

Thanks in advance
Chris

Comment: On Safari (on Mac) it isn't blurred, but the scale is wrong. Seems like within the iFrame you have a CSS rule for `#renderer > canvas` that sets the image in relative size which makes it look bad. But that's not on your side...

Comment: Thanks, I'd added the height and width to that - but have now removed it. Could you check now please?

Comment: It's still there, coming from fcs.css line 144. you don't need us to debug your code. If you have a specific question, please ask. If you are just looking for someone to talk you over CSS or debug your work, this is not the place...

Answer (score 0):

Try using attributes height="100%" width="100%"

Comment: If it is a simple answer post it in the comment.

Comment: For users with low reputation it's impossible to add a comment.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't edit the attributes - the iframe contents are generated elsewhere